# XPath wildcard matching different paths

Tags: xpath

I'm not quite able to figure out how to match both of these cases below with one XPath I've tried searching on wildcard matching but not seeming to find it. Is it possible to match both cases below with just one XPath or are 2 needed?

Sometimes it is like this:

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/span/strong/a
```

Other times just this:

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 1:

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/a | tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/span/strong/a
```

XPath 2:

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/(a | span/strong/a)
```

Comment: The second (more elegant and likely more performant) expression is not valid in XPath 1.0, but works with Saxon 9, but I couldn't locate the syntax in the XPath 2.0 spec. Do you have a pointer to that?

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-primary-expressions), then look at the _ParenthesizedExpr_. And if you can use XPath 2 instead of XPath 1.0, it's a really big step forward ;)

Answer (score 2):

By using

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/span/strong/a | tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]/a
```

you can select both paths in one query.

If you want all `/a`-Elements under `.../li[1]`, you can also use

```
tr[@id='someid']/td/ol/li[1]//a
```

(Note the double slash at the end). Source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)